# Is there a word expressing a contrast in two parallels statements, the second of which reverses the order of items in the first?

Tags: word-request

> Martyrs create faith, faith does not create martyrs. ([LINK](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BHgVzlHGYUC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=%22martyrs+create+faith+faith%22&source=bl&ots=dwYMlPNlWS&sig=UM8BBC_aJawaFD04KNfg3X9Ekao&hl=it&sa=X&ei=G3MuUbfcMsTh4QSx54CQAg&redir_esc=y))

Is there a word expressing a contrast in two parallels statements, the second of which reverses the order of items in the first?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of *[antimetabole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole)*, wikipedia says:

> In rhetoric, *antimetabole*  is the repetition of words in successive clauses, but in transposed grammatical order (e.g.,  “I know what I like, and I like what I know”). It is similar to chiasmus although chiasmus does not use repetition of the same words or phrases.

Other examples in the wikipedia article include:

> • “Eat to live, not live to eat.” Attributed to Socrates
>   •   “He who questions training only trains himself at asking questions.” The Sphinx, Mystery Men (1999)

Comment: dang it, you beat me by 2 whole minutes.

Comment: @Hellion, feel free to vote it up :)

Comment: There really is a word for everything.

Comment: Whilst this is true (and a nice word that fully answers the OP's question), it's an exceptionally rare word and Native English speakers are unlikely to know what it is or what it means. Consequently this is probably not a good choice of word for a new English Learner to use in normal everyday settings.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***[converse](http://www.britannica.com/topic/converse)***
as in "'Martyrs create faith,' but the converse is not true."  It doesn't imply contrast between the pair of statements, but it is a much more common word than *antimetabole* is.

For a given statement A → B, the converse is simply B → A. The order is changed but it is neither presumed true nor false.